# config for Kafka sink connector for mysql

Tags: curl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Trying to create a sink connector for mysql, installed following .JAR files in the "kafka/lib" folder:

mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar
kafka-connect-jdbc-5.3.1.jar
plugin path = /kafka/lib

following is the curl command:

curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/quickstart-mysql-sink/config -d '{"name":"quickstart-mysql-sink", "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector", "tasks.max":"1", "topics":"test", "connection.url":"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb", "connection.user":"xxxx", "connection.password":"xxxx", "auto.create":"true" }'

Error: {"error_code":405,"message":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}curl: (3) Port number ended with 'i' curl: (3) Port number ended with ',' curl: (3) Port number ended with 't' curl: (3) Port number ended with 'j' curl: (3) Port number ended with 'r' curl: (3) Port number ended with 'P' curl: (3) Port number ended with 't' curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1

The sink connector for mysql is not working, am i missing anything?

Additionally noticed on the connector console, getting
ERROR Uncaught exception in REST call to /connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper)
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found

Comment: Looks like you have posted the same question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252072/kafka-sink-connector-for-mysql

Comment: And please don't add unrelated tags